# Interesting cos(z) conformal mapping problem

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this conformal mapping problem that I was trying to do, but I got stuck.

If $Dz=\{z: -\frac{\pi}{2}<\mathrm{Re}(z)<\frac{\pi}{2} \text{ and } \mathrm{Im}(z)>0\}$ find $Dw$, where $w=\cos(z)$.

Now, I have used Euler's formula and got to somewhere. For $\cos(z)=u+iv$, I found that $u=\cos(x)\cosh(y)$ and $v=-\sin(x)\sinh(y)$. Because of $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\mathrm{Re}(z)<\frac{\pi}{2}$ I get that $u>0$, but the part that is giving me trouble is what happens with $v$? I see that $v>0$ for $-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<0$ and $v<0$ for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

What should I do now? Please, if you could explain it would help very much.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you determine whether $z \mapsto \cos z$ maps $D$ _onto_ the half-plane $\{ z : \Re z > 0 \}$?

Comment: I don't see what is so confusing about my question? Except that I don't know how to put inequilty signs, so if someone could edit that for me it would be nice.